# D3 SVG visualization using CSV data to style Topojson geometries

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm building a visualization with D3 in which I would like to dynamically style SVG elements according to variable values I've imported from a CSV file.

My current approach looks like this: I import geometry data from a Topojson file like so:

```
d3.json("geoms.json", function(error, data) {
    var path = d3.geo.path()
                 .projection(projection.translate([0.5*width, 0.5*height]));
svg.selectAll(".map")
       .data(topojson.object(data, data.objects.map).geometries)
       .enter().append("path")
       .attr("id", function(d) { return "c_" + d.id; })
```

And I import attribute data from a CSV file and attach various values and associated classes/categories to the DOM elements like this:

```
d3.csv("data.csv", function(data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) { 
        d3.selectAll("#c_" + d.ISO_A3)
          .attr("name", d.name)
          .attr("area", parseFloat(d.area))
          .attr("area_class", d.area_class)
          .attr(...
```

In the above snippet, `area` denotes the area of a country and `area_class` denotes the size class a country falls into (e.g., `area_class` could fall between 1 and 5 in an natural breaks classification that was pre-computed). Conceptually, geometries and attributes can be linked via `d.id` and `d.ISO_A3`, respectively.

I'm not sure if this approach is a good one or not, but I wanted to keep the geometry and the attribute data separate, so that the former are re-usable and so that I can plug-in more attribute data easily later on by adding variables to the CSV file and not messing with the Topojson file.

I now have troubles with using `area_class` to style the SVG elements. I thought I could use a dropdown menu, that would let me change the variable used to style the SVG elements (themes). The SVG element's class would change and it would be styled according to that class using CSS. `onchange`, the dropdown menu fires this:

```
function change_theme(dropdown) {
    var theme = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
    $("[id^='c_']").each(function(index){
        console.log($(this).attr('class'));
        console.log($(this).attr(theme));
        var prev_class = $(this).attr('class');
        $(this).addClass($(this).attr("class_" + theme)).removeClass(prev_class);
    });
}
```

On the console, this produces what I would expect e.g. something like:

```
class_1
2
```

i.e., the previous class this SVG element had and the numerical part of the new class as imported from the CSV file and attached to the SVG element as an attribute. However, the function fails to actually affect the class of the SVG elements and thus its appearance.

I'm not sure where this goes wrong and also if my approach is okay to start with (using separate Topojson and CSV files and how I attach the values from the CSV to the SVG elements)?

I appreciate any input, thanks!

Comment: Is that jquery you're using if so it doesn't work with SVG classes. http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13056

Comment: It looks like you have an additional `.attr` in your `.addClass` call -- shouldn't that be `$(this).addClass("class_" + theme)`?

Comment: @RobertLongson: Thanks, I had no idea.

@LarsKotthoff: Thank you. You are absolutely right. What would give the intended result is `$(this).addClass("class_" + $(this).attr(theme))`. But the problem of jQuery and SVG classes Robert pointed out meant that I needed to figure out yet another solution.

Thank you both very much for your help!

Comment: I ended up using native D3 to change classes instead of relying on jQuery (see @RobertLongson's comment) . Here is what I came up with and it seems to work (SO doesn't yet let me post this as answer):

    `function change_theme(dropdown) {
        var theme = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
        d3.selectAll("path[id^='c_']").each(function() {
            var item = d3.select(this);
            item.attr('class', 'class_' + item.attr(theme));
        });
    }`